# How to move static array property to superclass in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, inheritance, static-variables

I have several classes with a common ancestor, each with a static array property:

```
class Foo extends Base {
  static ary = [];
}

class Bar extends Base {
  static ary = [];
}
```

And because modification of `ary` is handled entirely from within `Base`, I'd also like to move the array definition into `Base`.

But when I change my code to:

```
class Base {
  static ary = [];
}

class Foo extends Base {
}

class Bar extends Base {
}
```

then `Base`, `Foo` and `Bar` will obviously share the same array instance.

How can I define `ary` in a way so that each subclass will have its own property, referring to its own instance?

---

My current work-around looks like this:

```
class Base {
  private static _ary: Array<any>;
  static get ary(): Array<any> {
    if (!this.hasOwnProperty('_ary')) {
      this._ary = [];
    }
    return this._ary;
  }
}

class Foo extends Base {
}

class Bar extends Base {
}

Foo.ary.push(1, 2, 3);
Bar.ary.push(4, 5, 6);

Foo.ary; // [1, 2, 3]
Bar.ary; // [4, 5, 6]
```

but it feels quite cumbersome, because (a) it involves a private property `_ary` and (b) the `ary` getter is called *every time* `ary` is accessed, although I need to run that code only *once* per subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly as you specified - but if you accept `ary` to be a method instead - you can implement required behavior like this:

```
class Base
{
    private static allAry = {};

    static ary(cls): Array<any>
    {
        let result = Base.allAry[cls.name];

        if (!result)
        {
            result = [];
            Base.allAry[cls.name] = result;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class Foo extends Base
{
    public static a()
    {
        Foo.ary(this).push(1);
        console.log(Foo.ary(this).length);
    }
}

class Bar extends Base
{
    public static b()
    {
        Bar.ary(this).push(1);
        console.log(Bar.ary(this).length);
    }
}

Foo.a(); // Prints 1
Bar.b(); // Prints 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have a similar work-around (I've updated my question). Is there a way to run that logic only once per instance instead of every time the array / method is accessed?